# Why my route deleteMany is not working in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I'm trying build a route to delete all my objects that have entity `"techs":[]`.

I'm training mongoose and made a mistake where an error happened, and I send wrong information to API.

So, I built the code:

```
router.delete("/delete", connectDatabase, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const resDB = await SchemaProjects.deleteMany({ techs: [] });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "OK",
      statusMensagem: "Projects sucefully deleted",
      response: resDB,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json("internal server error");
  }
});
```

but it goes to catch and returns:

> "internal server error".

My API...

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "6589873d4e3eb0cee59435dc",
        "type": "landing",
        "title": "Google Clone",
        "description": "Google Clone landinpg page",
        "techs": [],
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/wp9mHmq/google.png",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "658dc7bb77d42309479a0d79",
        "type": "landing",
        "title": "Google Clone",
        "description": "Google Clone landinpg page",
        "techs": [],
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/wp9mHmq/google.png",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "658dc7bd77d42309479a0d7b",
        "type": "landing",
        "title": "Google Clone",
        "description": "Google Clone landinpg page",
        "techs": [],
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/wp9mHmq/google.png",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "658de1f581c1748f5c5ce802",
        "type": "landing",
        "title": "Google Clone",
        "description": "Google Clone landinpg page",
        "techs": [],
        "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/wp9mHmq/google.png",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

What get me confused is, that's it working...

```
router.get("/get", connectDatabase, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const resDB = await SchemaProjects.find({ techs: [] });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "OK",
      statusMensagem: "Project sucefully deleted",
      response: resDB,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json("internal server error");
  }
});
```

and return data correctly of API, the same entity and value (`{ techs: [] }`)

Comment: In your `catch (error)` you should `console.log(error)` to see what it says.

Comment: Using `techs: []` in the `deleteMany` should still work. Make sure you are sending the correct request to the correct route handler.

Answer (score 0):

To delete documents where the array is empty you should use the [`$size`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator to check for array of length 0 like so:

```js
const resDB = await SchemaProjects.deleteMany({ techs: { $size: 0 } });
```

Or using the query builder syntax:

```js
const resDB = await SchemaProjects.where('techs').size(0).deleteMany();
```

Comment: What did `console.log(error)` say?

Comment: It's not working 

`router.delete("/delete", connectDatabase, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const resDB = await SchemaProjects.deleteMany({ techs: { $size: 0 } });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "OK",
      statusMensagem: "Projects sucefully deleted",
      response: resDB,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json("internal server error");
  }
});`

Comment: Yes that's fine but in order to see where the error occurs inside your `catch (error)` you need to write `console.log(error)` to see what it says in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, It's working, the problem was another route `delete('/:id')`, so the code thought that string "delete' was a id, now I put a route before and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should probably put that route with the `:id` after this one to give express an opportunity to match `/delete` first when the request passes through the middlewares.